# MFP Migration tool is not downloading using NPM install (with and without the zip file)

Tags: npm, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, mfp, ibm-mobilefirst-windows

When running `npm install -g mfpmigrate-cli` I keep getting the following error messages regarding .staging. One example is as follows:

> npm WARN tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'C:\Users[userName]\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules.staging\lodash.tostring-cb7aa638\package.json'

I have used two different machines and wifi connections to try and install this tool. Furthermore I have tried to reinstall my node_modules file and npm itself as that was recommended in other cases I have seen here. I get the same error when trying to install previous versions as well. Maybe I may be missing some folders due to my corp firewall, but as mentioned before, I have tried it on a different machine on different wifi and still get this issue.

IBM has removed the zip file since the last time I tried to use it. There were previous closed tickets with IBM regarding mfp-migrate not being able to install on machines but they have since fixed the bug that was causing that. I do not understand what can be wrong.
Could someone guide me on how to install this tool so I can convert my 6.3 application to 8.0.
[I have attached a snippet of just a few of the errors described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJagg.png)

Comment: It does not seem a StackOverflow question (programming)

Comment: @P5music My bad, IBM directs questions go here on their website: "Ask the community
You can post programming & setup-related questions in Stack Overflow and get answers from our extended IBM Mobile Foundation community.

Use this tag: ibm-mobilefirst"

Comment: I do not know if that's correct, indeed it could lead to undervotings of many questions tagged like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use below node and npm version and then try to install mfpmigrate-cli

> C:\Users>node -v
>   v6.17.1
>
> C:\Users>npm -v
>   3.10.10

Comment: Can you try on a different machine ?